# Poweredge 730xd Replace RAID 5 disk with alternate model?

Tags: dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, raid5

I have a Dell Poweredge R730XD with 24 x 1.2tb ST1200MM0088 (2.5, SAS 12Gbp 10K) disks in multiple raid 5 partitions.

One disk has failed - I have a brand new ST1200MM0099 disk available to replace the faulty drive. This appears to be the same size and specification? 
My question is if I hot swap the faulty ST1200MM0088 disk with the ST1200MM0099 will the system fail? What will the difference in performance be? (slowdown?)

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: As far as I remember, changing disk with the same capacity will work fine. Even if the biggest drive were replaced, the rebuild will start from 0 and possibly the RAID rebuild can fail. So if everything is the same (except the SN) you can easily change it :)

Answer (score 2):

If the drive is a 2.5 inch, 12Gbps SAS, 10K RPM, with the same size, then you can replace the old disk with the new one with no issue.

Edit: Actually Dell Says you can mix the bus speed and the spindle speed

> NOTE
>   : 
>   Mixing disks of different speeds (7,200 rpm, 10,000 rpm, or 15,000 rpm) and bandwidth 
>   (3 Gbps or 6 Gbps) PCIe while maintaining the same drive type (SAS or SATA) and technology 
>   (HDD or SSD) is supported.

Page 9: https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/common/rc_h310_h710_h710p_h810_ug_en-us.pdf